# GLSL dynamically indexed arrays

Tags: opengl, graphics, directx, glsl, hlsl

I've been using DirectX (with XNA) for a while now, and have recently switched to OpenGL. I'm really loving it, but one thing has got me annoyed.

I've been trying to implement something that requires dynamic indexing in the vertex shader, but I've been told that this requires the equivilant of SM 4.0. However I know that this works in DX even with SM 2.0, possibly even 1.0. XNA's instancing sample uses this to do instancing on SM2.0 only cards http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/mesh_instancing.

The compiler can't have been "unrolling" it into a giant list of if statements, since this would surely exceed the instruction limit on SM2 for our 250 instances.

So is DX doing some trickery that I can't do with OpenGL, can I manipulate OpenGL to do the same, or is it a hardware feature that OpenGL doesn't expose?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but out of curiosity, what's SM?

Comment: ["shader model"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Level_Shader_Language#Shader_model_comparison)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload an array for your light directions with something like glUniform3fv, then (assuming I understand what you're trying to do correctly) you just need your vertex format to include an index into this array (so there be lots of duplication of these indices if the index only changes once per mesh or something). If you don't already know, you can use glGetAttribLocation + glVertexAttribPointer to send arbitrary vertex attributes like this to the shader (as opposed to using the deprecated built-in attributes like gl_Vertex, gl_Normal, etc).

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm trying to do :). But how to I define the array in the shader and access it?

Answer (score 0):

From your link:

> Note that there is no single perfect
>   instancing technique. This must be
>   implemented in a different way on
>   Windows compared to Xbox 360, and on
>   **Windows the ideal technique requires
>   shader 3.0, but there is also a
>   fallback approach that will work with
>   shader 2.0**. This sample implements
>   several different instancing
>   techniques, so it can work on both
>   platforms and shader versions.

Not the emboldened part.  So ont hat basis you should be able to do similar instancing on shader model 3.  Shader model 2's instancing is usually performed using a matrix palette.  It sumply means you can render multiple meshes in one call by uploading a load of transformation matrices in one go.  This reduces draw calls and improves speed.

Anyway for OpenGL there was a lot of troubles finalising this extension and hence you need shader 4.  You CAN, however, still stick a per vertex matrix palette index in yoru vertex structure and do matrix palette rendering using a shader...

Comment: The SM3 technique uses 2 vertex streams, something completely different. This matrix palette is what I mean, but in DX I can pass vec3's as an array too, can I do that in OpenGL?

Comment: @Hannesh: You can always make glUniform*fv calls or you could look into GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object

Comment: I'll look into matrix palettes, what I actually want is just the normal space light direction for 6 cube faces. Maybe use a chain of if statements?